# rspec test to submit json data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to make a test to submit JSON data to my API endpoint, however it's not working.  After trying various suggestions from blogs and the rspec documentation I'm still failing.

> specs/controller/v1/devices_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe V1::DevicesController, type: :controller do

  it "updates device info" do
    @data = {}
    @device = FactoryGirl.create(:device)
    @data[:diagnostic_dns] = false
    @data[:diagnostic_ping] = false
    put :update, @data.to_json
    @data.reload
    response.should be_successful
  end

end
```

**I've also tried this in my test:**

```
  it "updates device info" do
    device = FactoryGirl.create(:device)
    device.diagnostic_dns = false
    device.diagnostic_ping = false
    put :update, :device, :format => :json
    response.should be_successful
  end
```

***Which results in this rspec failure:***

```
Failures:

  1) V1::DevicesController updates device info
     Failure/Error: put :update, @data.to_json

     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
```

> app/controllers/v1/devices_controller.rb

```
class V1::DevicesController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:show, :update], :if => Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }
  before_action :set_device, only: [:show, :update]
  respond_to :json

  def update
    if @device.update(device_params)
      render json: @device, status: :ok
    else
      render json: @device.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private

  def set_device
    @device = Device.find_by!(serial_number: params[:serial_number])
  end

  def device_params
    params.require(:device).permit(
      :serial_number,
      :name,
      :diagnostic_checkin_status,
      :diagnostic_dns,
      :diagnostic_ping,
    )
  end

end
```

> And my routes.rb file

```
       v1_device GET    /v1/devices/:serial_number(.:format)              v1/devices#show
                 PATCH  /v1/devices/:serial_number(.:format)              v1/devices#update
                 PUT    /v1/devices/:serial_number(.:format)              v1/devices#update
```

**UPDATE**
After changing my test submit to:

```
patch :update, params: {serial_number: device.serial_number, device: @data }, :format => :json
```

I'm now getting:

```
Failures:

  1) V1::DevicesController updates device info
     Failure/Error: response.should be_successful
       expected `#<ActionDispatch::TestResponse:0x005592458af9d0 @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Thread::Mu...:Headers:0x00559245826d10 @req=#<ActionController::TestRequest:0x005592458afcc8 ...>>, @variant=[]>>.successful?` to return true, got false
```

**UPDATE**
I added byebug to the controller and this is what `@device.errors` has it in:

```
@messages={:diagnostic_ping=>["can't be blank"], :diagnostic_dns=>["can't be blank"]}, @details={:diagnostic_ping=>[{:error=>:blank}], :diagnostic_dns=>[{:error=>:blank}]}>
```

So, the variables are not being set?

Comment: How're you validating the presence of those fields? I assume they're boolean and with just this information I'm going to guess you're likely doing `validates_presence_of :diagnostic_ping`, which [the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence) warn about

Comment: You're right, the validation was the issue.  I removed it and the test passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To adding parameter, you can use this.

```
specs/controller/v1/devices_controller_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe V1::DevicesController, type: :controller do
  let(:new_attributes) {
    FactoryGirl.attributes_for :device, diagnostic_dns: false, diagnostic_ping: false
  }

  it "updates device info" do
    @device = FactoryGirl.create :device
    put :update, params: {serial_number: @device.serial_number, device: new_attributes }, :format => :json
    response.should be_successful
  end

end
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't stress too much about getting RSpec to submit an actual JSON string to your code. Rails is in charge of turning that JSON into a params hash for you, so Rails should have the tests verifying they handle JSON properly. I would just do a normal test passing params with a `format: :json` verifying that you return the JSON you're expecting.

I believe that would look like

```
put :update, serial_number: @device.serial_number, device: @data, format: :json
```

Comment: This particular route is used by remote hosts, so I want to make sure the controller is doing it's job correctly.  Mainly, the remote host is building the JSON and submitting it to this API endpoint.

Comment: Right, but in your controller the only thing you had to do differently then any other web app was `render json: ...`, when it comes to looking at the params hash, rails already spotted it was JSON coming in and turned it into a params hash all the same for you, so you're none-the wiser about it being a JSON request. So, personally, I wouldn't worry too much about making sure your test passes in JSON, that to me is testing a rails feature, not my own code.

Comment: Gotcha... I updated my code above and used `byebug`.  It doesn't look like my params are getting passed.